# How can split on a comma except where it appears in brackets?

Tags: php, split

I want to split like this:

### Before:

```
TEST_A, TEST_B, TEST_C (with A, B, C), TEST_D
```

### After:

```
TEST_A
TEST_B
TEST_C (with A, B, C)
TEST_D
```

How can I split it?

Comment: Is the output to be text, HTML, an array or something else? The answer will help you to decide whether to use newline characters ("\n"), HTML breaks, or some other method.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes, I tried. But I can't split except comma in brackets

Comment: @Dave I know about regex. but, I can't make a code perfectly works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn’t going to help this time, so you will have to iterate through the characters.

Fact is, regular expressions aren’t very context-aware. For that reason, [you can’t use regular expression to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). This is why we’re better off iterating through the string ourselves.

```
function magic_split($str) {
    $sets = array('');  // Sets of strings
    $set_index = 0;     // Remember what index we’re writing to
    $brackets_depth = 0; // Keep track if we’re in brackets (or not)

    // Iterate through entire string
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        // Skip commas if we’re not in brackets
        if($brackets_depth < 1 && $str[$i] === ',') continue;

        // Add character to current list
        $sets[$set_index] .= $str[$i];

        // Store brackets depth
        if($str[$i] === '(') $brackets_depth++;
        if($str[$i] === ')') $brackets_depth--;

        if(
            $i < strlen($str) - 1 && // Is a next char available?
            $str[$i+1] === ',' &&   // Is it a comma?
            $brackets_depth === 0   // Are we not in brackets?
        ) $sets[++$set_index] = '';  // Add new set
    }

    return $sets;
}

$input = 'TEST_A, TEST_B, TEST_C (with A, B, C), TEST_D';
$split = magic_split($input);
```

Comment: It is nice. but, This code delete comma in bracket. :(

Comment: So, I add some code[ if($brackets_depth === 0 && $str[$i] === ',') continue; ] And then, It works great. Thank you!

Comment: @WebEngine My apologies, you’re completely right. I’ve modified the code if anyone happens to come across this question :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to match:

- a word not containing opening parentheses, nor coma : [^(,]+
- an expression between parenthesis: \([^(]+\)

  - or not... and without returning the match, so it becomes: (?:\([^(]+\))?)
- a coma, followed by some space : ,[\s]*

PHP Code:

```
$ar=preg_split("#([^(,]+(?:\([^(]+\))?),[\s]*#", "$input,", -1,
            PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Edit: it does not work if you don't have coma outside the parenthesis.
you'll have to add an extra coma after $input like modified above.

Comment: It is very great! However, if $input is 'TEST(A,B,C)', It returns 'TEST(' / 'A' / 'B' / 'C)' :(

Comment: oh you're right. just add an extra coma on the right.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution to this problem will depend on exactly what your specification is for identifying individual elements.

If you expect each one to begin with `TEST_`, then you could solve it fairly simply with a regular expression:

```
$input = 'TEST_A, TEST_B, TEST_C (with A, B, C), TEST_D';
$matches = preg_split('/,\s*(?=TEST_)/', $input);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "TEST_A"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "TEST_B"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "TEST_C (with A, B, C)"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "TEST_D"
}
```

This splits the string on commas followed by whitespace, using a [lookahead assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) test for the presence of `TEST_` at the beginning of the next item.

Answer (score 1):

You merely need to explode on comma-space and disregard any comma-spaces that are inside of parentheses.  `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` will consume all parenthetical expressions and dispose of them so that they are not used as delimiters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TGHbY))

```
$text = 'TEST_A, TEST_B, TEST_C (with A, B, C), TEST_D';

var_export(preg_split('~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|, ~', $text));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'TEST_A',
  1 => 'TEST_B',
  2 => 'TEST_C (with A, B, C)',
  3 => 'TEST_D',
)
```